# Ajaxを用いて非同期でコメント機能を実装したのですが、コメント投稿後、render処理でTemplate is missingエラーが表示されてしまう

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery

**環境**

ruby 2.7.2
rails 6.1
macOS

**前提**

下記の記事を参考に、非同期でのコメント投稿機能を実装いたしました。

[[Rails] Ajaxを用いて非同期でコメント機能の実装](https://qiita.com/yuto_1014/items/c7d6213139a48833e21a)

**解決したいこと**

コメント投稿機能を非同期で実装させたいです！

**試したこと**

renderで問題が発生しているため、`render :index`を仮で`redirect_to root_path`と変更した所、rootページへ遷移しました。
また、削除機能でも`render :index`を使用しているのですが、削除は正常に動作しています。

エラー文をググり、下記の参考記事を試してみたのですが、同じエラーが表示されてしまいました。

[Rails responseにrenderでjsファイルを返すには](https://qiita.com/hmuronaka/items/d7b6afa3cd62dfe207b4)

どのようにすればいいのか検討がついていない状態です。
わかる方がいましたらアドバイスいただけると幸いです。
何卒よろしくお願いします。

**発生している問題・エラー**

コメント投稿後、下記のエラー文が表示されてしまい、正常に動作していない状況です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**該当するソースコード**
`travel_records_controller.rb`

```
  def show
    @travel_record = TravelRecord.find(params[:id])
    @user = @travel_record.user
    # コメントの作成
    @comment = Comment.new
    # 新着順で表示
    @comments = @travel_record.comments.order(created_at: :desc)
  end
```

`comments_controller.rb`

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @travel_record = TravelRecord.find(params[:travel_record_id])
    #投稿に紐づいたコメントを作成
    @comment = @travel_record.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.save
    render :index
  end

  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    render :index
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:comment, :user_id, :travel_record_id)
    end
end
```

`index.js.erb`

```
$("#comments_area").html("<%= j(render 'index', { comments: @comment.travel_record.comments }) %>");
$("textarea").val('');
```

`travel_records/show.html.slim`

```
= render 'layouts/flash_messages'
#comments_area
  = render 'comments/index', comments: @comments
```

`comments/_index.html.slim`

```
= comments.count
| 件のコメント
h6.more[data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"]
  | もっと見る....
- comments.first(2).each do |comment|
  - unless comment.id.nil?
    p = link_to "@#{comment.user.name}", user_path(comment.user.id)
    p
      | コメント：
      = comment.comment
      - if comment.user == current_user
        = link_to travel_record_comment_path(comment.travel_record_id, comment.id), method: :delete, remote: true do
          i.fas.fa-trash[style="color: black;"]
    span = comment.created_at.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
#collapseExample.collapse
  - comments.offset(2).each do |comment|
    - unless comment.id.nil?
      p = link_to "@#{comment.user.name}", user_path(comment.user.id)
      p
        | コメント：
        = comment.comment
        - if comment.user == current_user
          = link_to travel_record_comment_path(comment.travel_record_id, comment.id), method: :delete, remote: true do
            i.fas.fa-trash[style="color: black;"]
      span = comment.created_at.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

`comments/_form.html.slim`

```
= form_with model: [travel_record, comment], url: travel_record_comments_path(travel_record) do |f|
  = f.text_area :comment
  = f.submit "コメントする", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記の参考記事をもとに自己解決できたので情報共有します。

[【Rails 6】（初心者向け）Ajax版最小構成CRUDアプリ（ページ移動をゼロに！）](https://qiita.com/take18k_tech/items/7d4917e30d4c879701ef)

結論：Rails 6.1 から仕様が変わり， `local: true`がデフォルトになったため、`js.erb`を呼び出すには `form_with`に`local: false`の記述が必要。

上記通り、コードを変更したことで、正常に動作させることができました！